# Generar Query en Web Service Java

Tags: java, webservice, sql

tengo un web service Restful en Java, he podido hacer transacciones CRUD sin problema, pero el desafío que me he encontrado es como hacer inner join y filtros en una consulta. Tengo un algo así:

```
@GET
@Path("buscar")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)

public List<Categorias> buscar(String descripcion) {
    javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery cq = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
    cq.select(cq.from(entityClass)); //Tengo entendido que aquí se hace pero desconozco el cómo. 
    javax.persistence.Query q = getEntityManager().createQuery(cq);
    return null;//Lo dejo null para armar la Query primero
}

@Override
protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
    return em;
}
```

Alguien podría guiarme en esto por favor...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo primero, mi recomendación es que no hagas los accesos a base de datos directamente en el Controller, utiliza una capa DAO para separar las capas (buenas prácticas). Al usar entidades puedes hacer uso de JPQL, que facilita las consultas:

```
String sql = "SELECT e FROM Entidad e INNER JOIN e.EntidadRelacionada er WHERE er.id = :id";
Query query = getEntityManager().createQuery(sql);
query.setParameter("id", 1);
Entidad entidad = query.getSingleResult();
```